# Taking n lines from a file which contains m lines, repeating the file lazily if necessary

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy

The desire for such a function came out of the necessity of generating a "source" of *Lorem ipsum* by repeating over and over the same 50 or something paragraphs of the text.

Actually I am curious to know how to do it in C++ (I guess `boost::hana` has something to offer in this respect), and [I have asked a question on StackOverflow about it aleady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903536/taking-n-lines-from-a-file-which-contains-m-lines-repeating-the-file-lazily-i).

However, to get a better understanding of the functional approach, here's my working solution in Haskell,

```hs
import System.IO (readFile)
main :: IO ()
main = (\x -> readFile "file" >>= putStrLn . unlines . take x . concat . repeat . lines)
       =<< return . read
       =<< getLine
```

where

- I'm not sure about the `return . read` type being the best choice there where it is (one reason being that it doesn't crash gracefully if `main` is fed with a non-numeric input), and
- I haven't written the lambda totally in point-free because I think it would be less readable.
- Most importantly, I'm not sure this works lazily in all its parts, but I'd really like to understand this bit.

The program above assumes the current directory contains a text file named `file`, which can contain something like this,

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Given this, one can compile and run obtaining this, for instance:

```bsh
ghc --make -dynamic program.hs && ./program <<< 7
line1
line2
line3
line1
line2
line3
line1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Even though `module Main` is implied when no header is given, I'd write it.
- `return . read =<< getLine = read <$> getLine = fmap read getLine` is a worse version of `readLn`. `read <$> getLine` is basically `return (error msg)` when the parse fails. This passes the bottoming value into the "pure" part of your code. `readLn badstr` crashes at a well defined time—upon its execution—and if you actually wanted to handle the error you'd use `Text.Read.readMaybe` or `readEither`.
- `concat . repeat` is `cycle`. Gets your point across better, doesn't it?
- `putStrLn . unlines` is a bug. It causes an extra newline in the input: `unlines` creates a trailing newline and `putStrLn` creates another. Use `putStr`.
- I don't hate the "expression" style here, but once we replace the `=<< return . read =<< getLine` with `=<< readLine` you may as well bring it to the front and use `>>=`, and at that point let's just use a `do`.
- `x`? Really?

So:

```
module Main (main) where -- not my style of spacing; but fine
import System.IO (readFile)

main = do
    wanted <- readLn
    contents <- readFile "file"
    putStr $ unlines $ take wanted $ cycle $ lines contents
```

Though I'd also take

```
main = do
    wanted <- readLn
    putStr . unlines . take wanted . cycle . lines =<< readFile "file"
```

Or, if you're attached

```
main = readLn >>= (\wanted -> putStr . unlines . take wanted . cycle . lines =<< readFile "file")
```

As to your concern about laziness; this is perfectly fine. `readFile` is lazy, and so is `lines`. `cycle` is actually better than `concat . repeat`; the latter keeps allocating `(:)`-cells as long as `take` consumes them, while `cycle` will simply connect a pointer that cycles back to the beginning of the output list, which should make it faster. Also, it errors instead of potentially looping forever on an empty input. `take` is of course lazy, and we've eliminated the excess laziness that would cause any parse errors to be triggered in it. Passing an infinite input (am on a *nix, so I used `yes(1)` and `mkfifo(1)`) into this program doesn't break it, which is a good litmus test for laziness.

Now, as to the functionality of this program: the `wanted` number should *really* be an argument, and so should the file (which should be optional and default to stdin). That's done with [`getArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs). This is complicated enough to move into new definitions. Let's get that `readMaybe` going, too. (Hoogle the new names to find the imports.)

```
dieWithUsage :: IO a
dieWithUsage = do
    name <- getProgName
    die $ "Usage: " ++ name ++ " lines [file]"

parseArgs :: [String] -> IO (Int, Handle)
parseArgs [] = dieWithUsage
parseArgs (wanted : rest) = (,) <$> getWanted <*> getHandle
    where getWanted = maybe dieWithUsage return $ readMaybe wanted
          getHandle = case rest of
              [] -> return stdin
              [path] -> openFile path ReadMode
              _ -> dieWithUsage
```

leaving

```
main = do
    (wanted, input) <- parseArgs =<< getArgs
    putStr . unlines . take wanted . cycle . lines =<< hGetContents input
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This is a good first review. I would also point out that `\x -> take x . cycle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` (or the `unlines . ... . lines` variant) is a good candidate for a function without any `IO`, which makes testing a lot easier later.